# OCMockito XCTest does not refresh tests when changes are made and tested

Tags: unit-testing, ios7, xcode5.1, xctest, ocmockito

I'm running into an issue where my iOS unit tests correctly execute the first time I run them on the device, but refuse to acknowledge any changes made after the initial run on either the device or simulator. If I uninstall the app and clean the project in xCode, then test again, the changes are visible. **What could be the simulator to ignore changes to tests and give me old results back?**

Below is an example of what I'm seeing - notice how uncommenting the XCTFail does nothing when the test is ran on the simulator again.

[image]

Running again with fail uncommented, the test should fail, but it does not recognize the change:

[image]

Comment: The next day tests on actual devices seem to work, but tests executed on the simulator (any of them) still cannot recognize changes :/

Comment: PS. the workaround that I'm currently using is to test in xCode 6 beta3, which seems to work much better

Comment: Interesting. Don't have such behaviour, so something really specific